# How to change an application Icon

Tags: permissions, icons

I would like to know if it's possible to change an application permission in order to change the icon. In this case, it's Steam, situated at `/usr/share/applications`. I don't know if I should change the permission of this one or the permission of the application itself situated at `/usr/bin`

Not very complicated but I hope someone will understand what I mean, else, how could I change the icon itself or if there's any other alternatives.

P.S.: The permissions are set for Root

Thank you.

EDIT: I tried alacarte, it's great, exactly what I was looking for, exept that when I change the icon, I get a little X. I tried with different images an all the same. Are there a specific image type I need to get?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open your terminal and type as

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends alacarte
```

Then after that open it.

Then by selecting the application and its new icon you can modify the application of the specific application.

Comment: Modify "the application of the specific application"? Did you mean "the icon of the specific application"?